# Ruby select! method missing after latest update

Tags: updates, ruby

When I tried to run some code after yesterday's update to Ruby 1.9, I got this error:

```
undefined method `select!' for ["58720262"]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

I got the same error when I tried it in irb. Does anyone know how I can get this method back? Is there a library I can downgrade or something? Thanks!

Comment: Recommend using `rbenv` or `RVM` to mange ruby versions.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out what went wrong.  I have both `ruby1.8` and `ruby1.9.1` installed on my machine, and when update-manager did its thing, it reverted all the links in `/etc/alternatives` back to 1.8. The `select!` method doesn't exist in 1.8.  I put my links back (ruby, irb, rdoc, ri) and everything works the way it's supposed to again.